# Javascript window.onbeforeunload not work without Alert

Tags: javascript

Hi I use javascript to save information after page going to be close or navigate to another page.My problem is when I call webservice in window.onbeforeunload it is not going to fire and I dont get result. But If I put alert at the end of function webservice going to fire and I get result.I don't want to use alert at all .Is there any way.my code is as follows:

```
    window.onbeforeunload = InitializeService;
     function InitializeService() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

            var url = "http://localhost:54329/WebServices/PageUnloadCall.asmx?op=Page_Unload";

           myReq.onreadystatechange = checkStatus1;

           myReq.open("GET", url, true); // true indicates asynchronous request

           myReq.send();

      //     alert("Your Call Record Has Been Saved!");

     }
     }
     function checkStatus1() {

         if (myReq.readyState == 4) // Completed operation
         {

             myReq.open("POST", "http://localhost:54329/WebServices/PageUnloadCall.asmx/Page_Unload", false);

             myReq.send();

         }
     }
```

As you can see in function InitializeService ,I dont want to use Alert there but if I dont I dont get result.

Comment: You don't ever get the request or the alert just allows the async call to finish? set to false and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks ,thats the only reason .I am trying it from 3 hours thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert is allowing the async call to finish allowing the response.  Change:

```
myReq.open("GET", url, true);
```

to:

```
myReq.open("GET", url, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be because the `onbeforeunload` is long gone (done, complete) before your webservice call returns. Your webservice call gets initiated and it probably reaches the server (check logs at server; add a log call to verify), but the browser decides not to wait - which is by design, because the user is navigating away from the page.

If your only goal is to report this event, you might be fine (as you're probably getting it), but if you intended to do anything AFTER, see if it'll work if you change the behavior of that service call to synchronous:

```
myReq.open("GET", url, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a synchronous request (don't know if it'll work):

```
myReq.open("GET", url, false); // false => synchronous request
```

Should cause the `unbeforeunload` handler to wait for the call to complete before returning, and letting the unload continue.